# Leave Yes/No Attribute Empty

Tags: attributes

Is it possible to not enter any value in a Yes/No attribute? My default is set to `No`, so every time I make a product, it is `No` and in the attribute edit menu, I can't change `No` to `empty`, only to `Yes`.

I need to do this because I'm synchronizing data automatically. I have two different sources for similar products and one sends me whether it has a certain feature, but the other just doesn't know whether the device has it or not. And I want to avoid setting the attribute to `No` even though the device has the feature, only my data source didn't tell me.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems like you should have three different options:

- Yes
- No
- Unknown (set as default)

So no you can't have no value for a Yes/No attribute.

Best solution would be to use a dropdown attribute with the three different options listed above and set Unknown option as default.

Comment: This is a simple and viable option. The alternative would be to make a custom source model, but this is much more complex. For ref: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/